# HikariCP/Spigot: Exporting with Eclipse no maven

Tags: eclipse, bukkit, hikaricp

I currently have a problem with HikariCP, I don't know how to export it in my JAR with Eclipse, note that I don't use maven.
If anyone has an idea, thanks in advance.

Error spigot:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariDataSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing happens because the .jar file does not contain the dependencies/libraries that you are using in development. In runtime, the plugin tries to load some third-party dependency classes but they are not found.

An easy solution to this is to select the option `Package required libraries into generated JAR` on the export menu. Here you have a screenshot:
[image]

Despite this, just an advice: I strongly recommend you use Maven or Gradle to manage your project build process and dependency import. The Maven Plugin that would pack libraries into the JAR file would be:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>your.main.class</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)